# Basic image editing on Python tkinter working but unwanted image scrolling course when dragging mouse

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The following code produces a nice Canvas with an image and I can draw a square on top of it. However:
a) I can't get the Canvas to not scroll.
b) I only want the image to appear and nothing else and can't get the sizes right

As you will see, I have even tried to stop the scrolling but it does not work all the time. In addition the image is never fully aligned with the Canvas nor the window even though I set the sizes to be the same for the three (root, canvas and image).

Here is the code (partly taken already from another example with some portions commented out):

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


try:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python3s
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import PIL as PILAll


class ExampleApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(self,  cursor="cross", width=640, height=480, confine=True, scrollregion=(10, 10, 10, 10), relief="groove", bg="blue")# and I have experimented with a few other options

        #self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        #self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        #self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        #self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.config()#yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
        self.canvas.config()#xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(ALL))
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        #self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,stick=N+S)
        #self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",     self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>",     self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",     self.on_button_release)
        self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self.on_button_leave)
        self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.on_button_enter)
        self.canvas.bind("<Double-Button-1>",     self.on_double_click)
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
        self.rect = None
        self.text = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None

        self.im = PILAll.Image.open("../../" + "image6.JPG")
        self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size


        self.canvas.config() #scrollregion=(0,0,self.wazil,self.lard))
        self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)


    out_of_scope = 1

    def on_button_leave(self, event):
        self.out_of_scope = 2
        print "out_of_scope....", self.out_of_scope

    def on_button_enter(self, event):
        print("entering...")
        self.out_of_scope = 1

    def on_double_click(self, event):
        print("double click")

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.start_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        if not self.rect:
            if self.out_of_scope == 1:
                self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, outline='blue', fill='yellow') #since it's only created once it always remains at the bottom

    def get_out_of_scope(self, x, y):
        return self.out_of_scope

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        curY = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        var=self.get_out_of_scope(event.x, event.y)
        print(var, event.x, event.y)
        if var == 1:
            w, h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
            if event.x > 0.9*w:
                self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, 'units')
            elif event.x < 0.1*w:
                self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, 'units')
            if event.y > 0.9*h:
                self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
            elif event.y < 0.1*h:
                self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
    # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
            self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)
        pass

root=Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
app = ExampleApp(root)
app.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by stackoverflow not allowing you to paste code, but stackoverflow doesn't do that. You can paste whatever code you want.

Comment: you have the `try: import Tkinter as tk ; except: import tkinter as tk` but you don't use `tk` at all, just `from Tkinter import *` which only works for python 2, I think you want `try: from Tkinter import * ; except ImportError: from tkinter import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code would benefit from being[reviewed](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) but I will try to limit myself to the question...

If the `canvas` needs to be the same size as the image why is it constructed with `width=640, height=480`?  You figure out the width and height of the image further down:

```
    self.im = PILAll.Image.open("../../" + "image6.JPG")
    self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size
```

(interesting variable name choice btw) so if `self.wazil` and `self.lard` represent the width and height of the image why don't you make that the width and height of the canvas?

```
    self.im = PILAll.Image.open("../../" + "image6.JPG")
    self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size
    self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.wazil, height=self.lard) #, ...)
```

then the canvas will be the correct size but the root window is still forcing itself to be *640x480* from:

```
root.geometry("640x480")
```

but since widgets will automatically scale themselves to the contents you can just comment that line out and it should be the correct size.

```
#root.geometry("640x480")
```

---

I should note that I was experiencing some very odd behaviour about the position of the image being 3 pixels too high and 3 pixels to the left, drawing the image with:

```
self.canvas.create_image(3,3,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)
```

fixed it for me but I have no idea why...

---

As for the scrolling you removed the parts about the scroll bars but you left in this in `on_move_press`:

```
        w, h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
        if event.x > 0.9*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, 'units')
        elif event.x < 0.1*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, 'units')
        if event.y > 0.9*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
        elif event.y < 0.1*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
```

This is the section of code that is occasionally scrolling the canvas (happened when I tried to resize the window) so again you can comment that section out and it shouldn't scroll anymore.

---

Last note which is unrelated to question, you have:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
```

But I'm pretty sure you mean to have:

```
def __init__(self,master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
```

since the first way you require a master argument but do not pass it to `Frame.__init__`.  When `Frame.__init__` receives a master of `None` it just uses the `Tk` instance which in your case is the same thing but if you used any other master it would cause very odd issues.

Comment: if you [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) please [label it appropriately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!